# How to calculate conditional probability of values in dataframe pandas-python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, probability

I want to calculate conditional probabilites of ratings('A','B','C') in ratings column.

```
    company     model    rating   type
0   ford       mustang     A      coupe
1   chevy      camaro      B      coupe
2   ford       fiesta      C      sedan
3   ford       focus       A      sedan
4   ford       taurus      B      sedan
5   toyota     camry       B      sedan
```

Output:

```
Prob(rating=A) = 0.333333 
Prob(rating=B) = 0.500000 
Prob(rating=C) = 0.166667 

Prob(type=coupe|rating=A) = 0.500000 
Prob(type=sedan|rating=A) = 0.500000 
Prob(type=coupe|rating=B) = 0.333333 
Prob(type=sedan|rating=B) = 0.666667 
Prob(type=coupe|rating=C) = 0.000000 
Prob(type=sedan|rating=C) = 1.000000
```

Any help, Thanks..!!

Comment: well, just do it :). `Prob(type=coupe|rating=A) = Prob(type=coupe and rating=A) /  Prob(rating=A)`.

Comment: What about using pd.crosstab?

Answer (score 20):

You can use `.groupby()` and the built-in [`.div()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
rating_probs = df.groupby('rating').size().div(len(df))

rating
A    0.333333
B    0.500000
C    0.166667
```

and the conditional probs:

```
df.groupby(['type', 'rating']).size().div(len(df)).div(rating_probs, axis=0, level='rating')

coupe  A         0.500000
       B         0.333333
sedan  A         0.500000
       B         0.666667
       C         1.000000
```

Comment: I believe the `level` parameter should be 0, and not 1.

Comment: Have you tried? I get missing values when I change the working version above to `level=0`. The `rating_probs` would have to align with the `rating` level, which is level 1. You can also change `level=1` to `level='rating`` to better see why this works. Just edited accordingly.

Comment: Interesting. I was getting results with `level=1`, but those results were incorrect. Changing it to `level=0` gave me the correct conditional probability values.

Comment: Just to clarify - are you saying the above results are wrong, or that you are getting different results using the above code?

Comment: The above results look correct. I was getting incorrect results in my dataset, which I corrected using `level=0`.

Comment: I put 90 rows in - get 89 back.

Comment: The example has 6 rows, the result returns 5 rows because not all pairs exist. Perhaps your case is similar @RaminMelikov?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groupby`:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'company': ['ford', 'chevy', 'ford', 'ford', 'ford', 'toyota'],
                     'model': ['mustang', 'camaro', 'fiesta', 'focus', 'taurus', 'camry'],
                     'rating': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                     'type': ['coupe', 'coupe', 'sedan', 'sedan', 'sedan', 'sedan']})

In [3]: df.groupby('rating').count()['model'] / len(df)
Out[3]:
rating
A    0.333333
B    0.500000
C    0.166667
Name: model, dtype: float64

In [4]: (df.groupby(['rating', 'type']).count() / df.groupby('rating').count())['model']
Out[4]:
rating  type
A       coupe    0.500000
        sedan    0.500000
B       coupe    0.333333
        sedan    0.666667
C       sedan    1.000000
Name: model, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

You need add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for add `0` values for missing pairs:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['rating'].unique(), df['type'].unique()])
s = (df.groupby(['rating', 'type']).count() / df.groupby('rating').count())['model']
s = s.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
print (s)
A  coupe    0.500000
   sedan    0.500000
B  coupe    0.333333
   sedan    0.666667
C  coupe    0.000000
   sedan    1.000000
Name: model, dtype: float64
```

And another solution, thanks [Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818063/how-to-calculate-conditional-probability-of-values-in-dataframe-pandas-python/46515289?noredirect=1#comment79984746_46515289):

```
s.unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```

Comment: `s.unstack(fill_value=0).stack()` should do perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

pd.crosstab(df.type, df.rating, margins=True, normalize="index")

```
   rating     A       B       C
   type                           
   coupe   0.500000  0.5  0.000000
   sedan   0.250000  0.5  0.250000
   All     0.333333  0.5  0.166667
```

Here the All row gives you probabilities for A, B, and C, now for conditional probabilities.

pd.crosstab(df.type, df.rating, margins=True, normalize="columns")

```
 rating   A      B       C     All
 type                                
 coupe   0.5  0.333333  0.0  0.333333
 sedan   0.5  0.666667  1.0  0.666667
```

Here your conditional probabilities are in the table for example conditional probability for a given type is a coupe and it has an A rating is 0.5 in row coupe and column A.
Prob(type=coupe|rating=A) = 0.5

Comment: This is a very clean and concise way to do it! Just requires one to learn how the crosstab function works. Very useful.

Answer (score -1):

first, convert into a pandas dataframe. by doing so, you can take advantage of pandas' groupby methods.

```
collection = {"company": ["ford", "chevy", "ford", "ford", "ford", "toyota"],
              "model": ["mustang", "camaro", "fiesta", "focus", "taurus", "camry"],
              "rating": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B"],
              "type": ["coupe", "coupe", "sedan", "sedan", "sedan", "sedan"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(collection)
```

then, groupby based on events (ie rating).

```
df_s = df.groupby('rating')['type'].value_counts() / df.groupby('rating')['type'].count()
df_f = df_s.reset_index(name='cpt')
df_f.head()  # your conditional probability table
```

Comment: I put 90 rows in - get 89 back.