# Conditional probability based on variables selected dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi, probability

Say I have a dataframe as below.

```
company model   rating  type    year
ford    mustang A   coupe   2018
chevy   camaro  B   coupe   2018
ford    fiesta  C   sedan   2021
ford    focus   A   sedan   2022
ford    taurus  B   sedan   2021
toyota  camry   B   sedan   2018
```

I want to calculate conditional probabilities but dynamically, based on the selections made in PowerBI. The final conditional probability needs to be displayed in PowerBI.

I am trying to calculate the conditional probabilities in Python.

So I want to calculate the probability of 'ratings' column conditional on the selections made on powerBI.

So if user selects, `year = 2018`, then

```
P(rating = A | year = 2018)
P(rating = B | year = 2018)
P(rating = C | year = 2018)
```

In another case if user selects, `year = 2018 and company = Toyota`

```
P(rating = A | year = 2018, company = Toyota)
P(rating = B | year = 2018, company = Toyota)
P(rating = C | year = 2018, company = Toyota)
```

1. I am trying to get the user selection made in powerBI as a variable and create a process to use it as a variable in python script. Then based on these variables calculate the conditional probability and display it in powerBI. Is it possible to export the user selections made in powerBI into a variable in powerBI? From powerBI, I can create a measure using `SELECTEDVALUE` to capture the selections made in PowerBI, but how can this be linked into python.
2. To calculate the conditional probability between two events I have used the approach in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818063/how-to-calculate-conditional-probability-of-values-in-dataframe-pandas-python?rq=3).

   rating_probs = df.groupby('rating').size().div(len(df))

   df.groupby(['type', 'rating']).size().div(len(df)).div(rating_probs, axis=0, level='rating')

How can this be extended to calculate the conditional probability of several events? (e.g. `P(rating = C | year = 2018, company = Toyota)`